# Member initialization while using delegate constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, ctor-initializer

The C++ standard does not allow delegate constructors and member initializers in a single mem-initializer-list, yet the following code compiles fine with clang++ and g++.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 
class Shape {
public:
        Shape();
};
 
class Circle : public Shape {
public:
        std::string name;
        Circle(std::string name);
};
 
Shape::Shape() {
        std::cout << "Shape constructor" << std::endl;
}
 
Circle::Circle(std::string name) : Shape::Shape(), name(name) { /* <--- Expected an error here! */
        std::cout << "Circle constructor" << std::endl;
}
 
int main() {
        Circle c("my_circle");
        std::cout << c.name << std::endl;
 
        return 0;
}
```

The relevant quote from the C++ 20 standard is (emphasis mine):

> (§11.10.2/6) A mem-initializer-list can delegate to another constructor of the constructor’s class using any class-or-decltype that denotes the constructor’s class itself. If a mem-initializer-id designates the constructor’s class, **it shall be the only mem-initializer**; the constructor is a delegating constructor, and the constructor selected by the mem-initializer is the target constructor.[...]

Did I misread the C++ standard? Do clang++ and g++ deviate from the standard here?

Comment: Delegation is to other constructors of the *same* class.  (Also, don’t write `Shape::Shape`; one is enough.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You are not using a delegating constructor.

A delegating constructor calls another constructor *in the same class*.

For example, in:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int) : Foo("delegate") {} // #1
    Foo(std::string) {} // #2
};
```

#1 and #2 are both constructors for `Foo`, and constructor #1 delegates to constructor #2.

In your case, you have a class that is derived from another class, and in:

```
Circle::Circle(std::string name) : Shape::Shape(), name(name)
```

You are initializing the base `Shape` portion of the `Circle` object, by calling `Shape`s default constructor.  You then move on after that to finish initializing the rest of the members of the `Circle` class.  This is not a delegating constructor.